# PayPal Express Check Out Digital Goods strange behavior

Tags: api, paypal, sandbox

I have set up Express Checkout payments through wizard in a sandbox. 
Made a couple of test transactions. Then it stopped working. No changes were done, though.

After logging in and pressing Pay button on the Paypal webpage it shows LOADING and it keeps loading forever, nothing happens.

I tried online proxy, i.e. zend2.com. Idea is that you can surf web through that site. Payment went through.

So I setup the same online proxy script on my server. And it worked again. Through my server!  If I navigate to the site through my own site it just works.
http://fermerius.hostoi.com/glype/index.php - proxy 
http://fermerius.hostoi.com/ppp/  - store.

But it won't load if you go directly to the store. It shows LOADING...............

All code I took from the wizard. Nothing was added. Just to test the very basics of it.

Can anybody shed some light on the issue ? Why is that like this ? What can be done to fix it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working again. Probably was a problem on their end.